# RunTime error solution

Tags: java, runtime-error

I have all the classes compiled and i create an array of Items(superclass of all) and i put different kinds of products:

```
aItems[1] = new Motherboard("970a",2014,200.0,"GIGABYTE","INTEL",64,5);
aItems[2] = new Motherboard("gb4",2012,150.0,"ASROCK","AMD",32,4); 
aItems[3] = new Proccesor("I5",2010,180.0,"INTEL",3.3,4);
aItems[4] = new Proccesor("I7",2014,900.0,"INTEL",4.0,4); 
aItems[5] = new Gcard("RADEON",2012,300.0,"GIGABYTE","AMD",4) ;
aItems[6] = new Gcard("RADEON",2010,200.0,"SAPPHIRE","NVIDIA",2); 
aItems[7] = new Ram("IO",2010,100.0,"ASUS","DDR",4,1600);
aItems[8] = new Ram("RADIOACTIVE X",2012,160.0,"CRUCIAL","DDR3",8,2000); 
aItems[9] = new HardDrive("E2",2013,100.0,"WD","SSD",2.5,750);
aItems[10] = new HardDrive("LM",2012,150.0,"HP","HDD",3.5,1000) ; 
aItems[11] = new Monitor("CFA90",2014,180.0,"SAMSUNG","LCD","23,5","1080","HDMI");
aItems[12] = new Monitor("27EA",2013,280.0,"ASUS","LED","28","1080","HDMI"); 
aItems[13] = new Mouse("Taipan",2013, 80.0, "Razer","Optical", "wired");
aItems[14] = new Mouse("M9Q",2013, 80.0, "Microsoft","laser", "wireless");
aItems[15] = new Keyboard("Blackwidow", 2014, 130.0, "Razer", "wired");
aItems[16] = new Keyboard("GK10", 2013, 100.0, "CM Storm", "wireless");
aItems[17] = new Printer("PS3H", 2012, 90.0, "HP", "laser" , "colored");
aItems[18] = new Printer("SPP5", 2013, 190.0, "SAMSUNG", "inkjet" , "black and white");
```

Then i want to take each object of the array and by calling methods get i want to create a txt file with the details of these items. But it gives me this runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Keyboard cannot be cast
 to Mouse
    at mainApp3.run(mainApp3.java:930)
    at acm.program.Program.runHook(Program.java:1592)
    at acm.program.Program.startRun(Program.java:1581)
    at acm.program.Program.start(Program.java:838)
    at acm.program.Program.start(Program.java:1250)
    at acm.program.Program.main(Program.java:1340)
```

Comment: The error is very explicit. Check what you have in line 1006 of your mainApp3.java file.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 28
        at mainApp3.run(mainApp3.java:930)
        at acm.program.Program.runHook(Program.java:1592)
        at acm.program.Program.startRun(Program.java:1581)
        at acm.program.Program.start(Program.java:838)
        at acm.program.Program.start(Program.java:1250)
        at acm.program.Program.main(Program.java:1340)
And the line 930 is:  'if(aItems[i] != null) { '

Comment: It would be better if you added additional information of that amount in an edit of the post.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to cast the Keyboard class to Mouse. Something like

```
Keyboard kybrd = new Keyboard();
Mouse mse = (Mouse) kybrd;
```

Something like that, I am not sure what you have there.

And that is causing the expection.

> Keyboard cannot be cast to Mouse

You should need to check what is the error that the compiler is showing to you at the line 1006,

```
at mainApp3.run(mainApp3.java:1006)
```

It is a reference to the error location. Trying hovering over to it.